# Scss: @include media-breakpoint-down: Undefined mixin but I import bootstrap class

Tags: html, angular, sass, angular-material, scss-mixins

I tried to use @include media-breakpoint-up in Angular but when compile get this error

Bootstrap 5.1.13

Angular CLI: 10.2.4

Node: 14.17.2

OS: win32 x64

Angular: 10.2.5

```
ERROR in Module build failed (from ./node_modules/sass-loader/dist/cjs.js):
SassError: Undefined mixin.
  ╷
6 │ ┌         @include media-breakpoint-down(md) {
7 │ │             width: 100%;
8 │ │             margin: 0 10px 0 10px;
9 │ └         }
```

style class

```
.mat-form-field{
        width: 460px;

        @include media-breakpoint-down(md) {
            width: 100%;
            margin: 0 10px 0 10px;
        }
    }
```

import in main.scss
`@import '~bootstrap/scss/bootstrap-utilities';`

bootrap class in html working normally

where is wrong?
Thanks

I tried to import every single bootsrap class (in correct order), i tried to restart Angular ng serve but never working

Comment: In which file do you try to use the mixing? In main.scss?

Comment: No, in a component file, but I import main.scss in the global scss file (default style.scss)

Comment: If you want to use it in a component file you also need to import it in component file I suppose.

Comment: Works! it's very strange because the import should be global, thanks

Comment: That's not how Angular works, you have to import it to every component where you need it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As suggested by cloned you have to import the bootstrap file on each SCSS component.

Answer (score 13):

```
@import 'node_modules/bootstrap/scss/functions';
@import 'node_modules/bootstrap/scss/variables';
@import 'node_modules/bootstrap/scss/mixins';
```

these imports are needed for it to work

Comment: is there any way to import these only once (In Angular), assume we have several style files, then it doesn't make any sense to import them every time separately. Thanks